# Fill Entire Rotated <th> with Background Color

Tags: html, css, background-color, css-tables

This is one I've never came across before and see no answers on Stack Overflow or elsewhere for. Here is a screencapped excerpt of a comparison chart I am creating:

[image]

As required by the wireframes, the `<th>` text is rotated 270 degrees, which also require a "zebra-striping" of all the even columns with a grey background. The `<td>`s fill the background area perfectly, but the rotated `<th>`s only fill the background behind the text. I have applied a height of 100% as suggested by other, un-rotated `th` examples, to no avail, and trying to add a width of 100% throws the entire table off. There has to be a simple solution to this I'm otherwise unable to find. Many thanks for any recommendations you can provide.

**Update:** Although I thought I had provided sufficient CSS to explain my issue, as requested, here are the relevant styles being applied here for this rotated `th`:

```css
th.headertext {
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    text-align: left;
    bottom: 56px;
    position: relative;
}

td:nth-child(even), th:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #efefef;
}

th {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 100%;
}

td, th {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 6px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Give us your code, and we try to give you some answers :)

Comment: What you want to do is to give the rotated headers a `line-height` equal to their `width`, either using `CSS` or on the fly, with `javascript`. If you don't want the table layout to be affected, you probably want to use `absolute` positioning. There's no *clean* way of doing this. It's gonna be hacky either way and it's not guaranteed to work cross-browser. I suggest  you glue a chair to the ceiling and invite the designer of the page over and ask them to *take a sit* ?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Gluing the chair to the ceiling is an elegant solution, but I'll see if anyone else has another solution first. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to rotate the `th`s themselves, right? Bad idea. The `th`s themselves will only be as wide as their unrotated height would be.
So one solution, but only if you know the `td`s all have the same width, is to give the `th`s that height.

A much better solution is to put some divs in the `th`s and rotate those. Then you're not dependent on all cells being the same width.

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-top:1px solid #ccc;
}

th.headertext div {
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    line-height:4em;
}

td:nth-child(even), th:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #efefef;
}

th {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    /*height: 100%;*/
    /*line-height: 100%;*/
}

td, th {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 6px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="headertext"><div>left</div></th>
    <th class="headertext"><div>middle</div></th>
    <th class="headertext"><div>right</div></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>left</td>
    <td>middle</td>
    <td>right</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Moving content in rotated child and leaving the background in parent seems to do the trick. Solid thinking.

Comment: Because there are the same-sized images in the associated `td`s, giving the precise height after moving the text into `div`s did the trick. Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Do like this, Replace "Image" with Actual Images

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
th:nth-child(2n+1) span {
    background: #E4E4E4;
}
th{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    
 height: 50px;
 
}

td:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background: #E4E4E4;
}
td {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
 border-top:solid 1px #acacac;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th><span>Brush</span></th><th><span>Roll</span></th><th><span>Spray</span></th><th><span>Liquid</span></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Image</td><td>Image</td><td>Image</td><td>Image</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Image</td><td>Image</td><td>Image</td><td>Image</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The <td>s _are_ only images, and your code snippet demonstrates the same issue I presented in my screencap above. Hard to know why anyone would vote this response up since it doesn't work.

Comment: Mohammad, if you ask your friends to vote you up, they should at least vote answers that actually work...